# If a power supply supplies 3 amps, does this mean that 3 amps are always in the circuit, regardless of load?

Tags: power-supply, amperage

If I have a power supply that says +5.0V/3.0A, does that mean that it can go up to 3 amps or does that mean it always has 3 amps in the circuit all the time?

If I need something that takes 500mA, and I connect it to a breadboard, proto board, or PCB, will it only pull the 500mA?

Comment: Short answer: No.

Comment: multiple answers, yes, no , yes